# Only Using Colours From A Specific Part of a Picture For Style Transfer

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, image-thresholding

I've got a neural style transfer model. I'm currently working on trying to use different parts of an image to transfer different pictures. I'm wondering how can I get the model to just use the colours present in an image. Below is an example:

[image]

[image]

The picture above is the style image that I have gotten from using thresholding along with the original image. Now the transferred picture is below:

[image]

Obviously it's transferred some of the black parts of the image but I only want the non black colours present to be transferred. Below is my code for my model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision.utils import save_image


class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()

        self.chosen_features = ["0", "5", "10", "19", "28"]


        self.model = models.vgg19(pretrained=True).features[:29]

    def forward(self, x):
        # Store relevant features
        features = []

        for layer_num, layer in enumerate(self.model):
            x = layer(x)

            if str(layer_num) in self.chosen_features:
                features.append(x)

        return features


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
def load_image(image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    image = loader(image).unsqueeze(0)
    return image.to(device)

imsize = 384

loader = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Resize((imsize, imsize)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        # transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ]
)

original_img = load_image("Content Image.jpg")
style_img = load_image("Adaptive Image 2.jpg")

# initialized generated as white noise or clone of original image.
# Clone seemed to work better for me.

generated = original_img.clone().requires_grad_(True)
# generated = load_image("20epoctom.png")
model = VGG().to(device).eval()


# Hyperparameters
total_steps = 10000
learning_rate = 0.001
alpha = 1
beta = 0.01
optimizer = optim.Adam([generated], lr=learning_rate)

for step in range(total_steps):
    # Obtain the convolution features in specifically chosen layers
    generated_features = model(generated)
    original_img_features = model(original_img)
    style_features = model(style_img)

    # Loss is 0 initially
    style_loss = original_loss = 0

    # iterate through all the features for the chosen layers
    for gen_feature, orig_feature, style_feature in zip(
        generated_features, original_img_features, style_features
    ):

        # batch_size will just be 1
        batch_size, channel, height, width = gen_feature.shape
        original_loss += torch.mean((gen_feature - orig_feature) ** 2)
        # Compute Gram Matrix of generated
        G = gen_feature.view(channel, height * width).mm(
            gen_feature.view(channel, height * width).t()
        )
        # Compute Gram Matrix of Style
        A = style_feature.view(channel, height * width).mm(
            style_feature.view(channel, height * width).t()
        )
        style_loss += torch.mean((G - A) ** 2)

    total_loss = alpha * original_loss + beta * style_loss
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if step % 500 == 0:
        print(total_loss)
        save_image(generated, f"Generated Pictures/{step//500} Iterations Generated Picture.png")
```

Any idea of where to potentially go as well would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want some ways to preserve non black color in your style transfer model I suggest checking out the github repo [here](https://github.com/rrmina/neural-style-pytorch). It has .ipnyb notebooks with entire training pipelines, model weights, a good readme, etc. to reference. According to their readme, they try to implement this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05897.pdf) on preserving color in neural artistic style transfer which should help you. You can also referecne other repos and run some of them on collabs in this paper of codes repo [here](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/preserving-color-in-neural-artistic-style) though I do suggest looking at the first repo first.

If you want to color transfer outside your styles transfer model and rather have two images that transfer color with the help of some functions in a linrary, then I recommend looking at this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/)

Sarthak Jain

Comment: This is so so useful thank you! Yeah the idea for me is to get the foreground of a style image and style transfer that to the foreground of the content image and then do the same for the background. This would leave me with 2 different images which I just have to merge together to get a final style transfer if that makes sense?